# How to explain this property of totient?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I am running a program to search for solutions of $$\varphi(pm+1)=\varphi(pm+p+1).$$

So far, for $m=1,\ldots,327$ solutions have been found (some relatively large).

(in the body of the question, $p$ is a natural number, not necessarily prime)

> I would  like to conjecture that for every $m \in \mathbb N$ there exists natural number $p \in \mathbb N$ such that $\varphi(pm+1)=\varphi(pm+p+1)$

- Is this known to be true?
- If not known to be true, is there some evidence that totient could have (or not have) this interesting property?

*Update*: I stopped the program at $m=407$ since it was taking a long long time to find solution for $m=407$ (if there is any), but all $m=1,\ldots,406$ have a solution.

*Update 2*: Currently, the program is running the code for approx. half an hour just for $m=490$, and yes, the solutions exist for $m=1,\ldots,489$

*Update 3*: It seems that it is rare that for some $k \in \mathbb N$ there do not exist some $p$´s such that we do not have $\varphi(pm+k)= \varphi(pm+p+k)$ for all $m$´s, and a research of when that fails to be true seems to be one possible avenue of research.

Comment: Ah, this is hardly true! :(

Comment: The program is taking a long long time at m=407.

Comment: Is this the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601590/even-more-surprising-conjecture

Comment: @GerryMyerson Not, but very different, there is investigation of pm+m+1 and here of pm+p+1, me and Peter are collaborating in some chatrooms.

Comment: OK, sorry – still, I think it's good for each question to link to the other.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No worries, you just did not see the difference at first glance.

Answer (score 6):

It might just be a matter of randomness.  Seeing no reason for $\varphi(pm+1)$ and $\varphi(p(m+1)+1)$ to be especially related, we might imagine heuristically that 
$\varphi(pm+1)$ and $\varphi(p(m+1)+1)$ have probability $\sim \text{constant}/(pm)$ of being equal.  Since $\sum_m 1/m = \infty$, it would then be reasonable to expect there to be
infinitely many $m$ for which this is the case.  Of course this is not a proof.

This also suggests that if a small $m$ is not found for a particular $p$, you might need to look very far (something like $\exp(\text{constant}/p)$) before finding an $m$ that works.

Comment: I have found some $k$ for which for some small $m$ it seems that there is no $p$ such that $\varphi(pm+k)=\varphi(pm+p+k)$ but both such $k$ and $m$ seem to be very rare.

Comment: Nice answer. Although the "matter of randomness" actually involves nothing random...

Comment: Agreed, it's not really random, but a random model can give useful heuristics, as with Cramér's random model for the primes.